# How to provide solutions to both React and non-React consumers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jss

I am developing a reusable set of UI React components using JSS, which are available in both ES5/ES6 modules. Is there a generator or pre-processor that can transform React/JSX into raw HTML and JSS into CSS?

Comment: "Transpile JSX to JavaScript", likewise with JSS -> CSS. Should be loads of tutorials

Comment: I doubt you'll have much luck trying to make a React plugin that can be somehow converted or transpiled to work completely without React. But any module that you write in pure JavaScript/CSS should work anywhere, since it will be framework independent.

Comment: Transpile all your code to vanilla JS/HTML/CSS and bundle/ship those. Babel/webpack will be a great place to start. As I said above, there are loads of tutorials online

Answer (score 0):

Try [React Studio](https://reactstudio.com/), it allows you write design/code in React style (e.g State/Props/Components/Flows/etc...) and much more features on their website...

Although it does not compile to "pure" HTML/CSS like you asked, but it can be used as a prototype/design tool with a good integration with Sketch, so any other developer/designer can also use it even if they don't understand React

Answer (score 0):

Follow this issue regarding static extraction from JSS if thats what you need https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/579